# HTML and data array both in same ajax response?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Im making an ajax call and Im reciving `html` response, I `append` that data with `success:` parameter.

Is there a way to also send `data array` with that same request which will not output if response is `appended` but could be used in different location / element?

I looked for answer, I swear and I didn't find anything useful or understandable.

I would set my `html` as response array first element and then add my data array as response second element but there's no way I could push that `html` to array and `append` it later.

---

**Update:**

```
$i = 0;

//Forming data array
while( $i < 3) {

    $data_array .= "{ ";
    $data_array .= "'customIcon': new google.maps.MarkerImage('" . $marker_image . "', null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(50, 69)), ";  
    $data_array .= "'latLng': new google.maps.LatLng(" . $coordinate[0] . ", " . $coordinate[1] . "), ";
    $data_array .= "'postId':'" . get_the_ID() . "', ";
    $data_array .= "'postType': 'red', ";
    $data_array .= "'alreadyLoaded': false, ";
    $data_array .= " }," . "\n";

$i++;
}


//Response
$response = array();
array_push ( $response, $results_html, $data_array, $count );
echo json_encode( $response );



//In ajax success:
console.log( [response[1]] );

//It should have 4 items but it's containing only 1 item that is single long string from all 4 object

//I'll get Google Map error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined
```

Comment: Sounds like you could use JSON to return an array with the html in the first element and the other part in the second. Show your code and what you've tried for a more specific answer.

Comment: @Terminus The problem is that `html` is _generated_ in `while` loop and is using WordPress `get_template_part()` to give every item in `while` this template. I even can't imagine how tricky this would be. There isn't seriously any other way to _"hide"_ data into `html` that could be retrieved and used when request is complete?

Comment: Pass it as the value of a hidden element in the HTML code.

Comment: Does wordpress automatically echo the html? You could always call `ob_start()` before the while loop and then `ob_getclean()` after (may want to check the docs on those). Or, is there some way to add `data-` attributes to the elements?

Comment: @Terminus I looked into it and I could use alternatives to `get_template_part()` that doesn't automatically `echo` it and I could save it as variable. I could add to data but is it good idea to send something like this `[ { array of hundreds, maybe even thousands of arrays with each have 4 to 5 values }, single-value ]` inside `html` `data-` or `value=`?

Comment: Well since you're not immediately echoing I guess the server is having to keep more data in RAM so that would put more stress on the server(?that's a total guess, I don't know that much) but as far as the browser, it'd only be receiving a little extra data (one small extra array?). No big deal? If you need that extra value than you need that extra value... Backtracking a bit: by "single extra value" is that all you're trying to add? Just wrap it in some unique characters, echo it with the rest of the stuff either before or after the loop, and than use JS to pull out the data before rendering

Comment: It actually kinda sounds like you've got it but if you still need help, I can't imagine the scenario with just the info provided. If you post the code you're using, i can post an answer. In either case, happy programming!

Comment: @Terminus I've updated my question, maybe you can help me.

Comment: Solo's updated answer seems like a really good solution. If you can explain why it doesn't suit your needs, I can write an answer that does (or he'll update his;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments to the question, @Terminus was setting you on the right track. As for your issue with rendering, you'll want to store the rendered HTML into a variable. You can use that using ob_ to create a temporary response stream that you can then save to a variable. Consider the following:

```
$myHtml = '';
ob_start();
// Render your HTML here whether its get_template_part() or echo, it will only save to the temporary stream
$myHtml = ob_get_clean();

// Now return your JSON
echo json_encode(array(
       'parameter1' => 'paramvalue',
       'parameter1' => 'paramvalue',
       'responseHtml' => $myHtml,
   ));
```

Now your jQuery looks like this

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'yourajaxurlhere',
    data: { },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(__respData) {
        var __myHtml = __respData.responseHtml;
        var __param1 = __respData.parameter1;
        var __param2 = __respData.parameter2;
    }
});
```

Hope that helps.

Update Based On Your Update:

Try this approach:

```
$i = 0;

//Forming data array
$dataArray = array();
while( $i > 3) { // side note this condition concerns me based on your ++ iterator
    array_push($dataArray, array(
        'customIconMarkerImage' => $marker_image,
        'lat' => $coordinate[0],
        'lng' => $coordinate[1],
        'postId' => get_the_ID(),
        'postType' => 'red',
        'alreadyLoaded' => false
    ));

    $i++;
}


//Response
$response = array();
array_push ( $response, $results_html, $data_array, $count );
echo json_encode( array(
    'dataArray' => $dataArray,
    'results_html' => $results_html,
    'count' => $count
));
```

Then in your jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    url: '', data: {}, dataType: 'json',
    success: function(__resp) {
        var __myMarkup = __resp.results_html;
        var __myDataArray = __resp.dataArray;
        var __myCount = __resp.count;

        $.each(__myDataArray, function(__daIndex, __da) {
            // Do javascript / googlemaps stuff here.
            var __customMarker = new google.maps.MarkerImage(__da.customIconMarkerImage, null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(50, 69));
            var __latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(__da.lat, __da.lng);

            var __postId = __da.postId;
            var __postType = __da.postType;
            var __alreadyLoaded = __da.alreadyLoaded;
        });
    }
});
```

Does it make sense what I changed? Basically you were trying to have javascript functionality be returned within your JSON, which you can't do. Instead I modified it so your JSON returns the VALUES that you need in order to run javascript using that information. Let me know if that helps you along.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Thank you for quick response!

Comment: Everything seems to work only that one of my parameters is array with structure `[ { value1: 'value', value2: 'value', value3: 'value' }, { value1: 'value', value2: 'value', value3: 'value' }, { value1: 'value', value2: 'value', value3: 'value' }, ]`  how do I convert it back from JSON because it generates error?

Comment: Your return parameter in PHP has that structure? I'm not quite sure I understand.

Comment: Im using structure like this `$output .= "{ ";` and  `$output .= "value1: 'value', ";` etc. Last line is `$output .= " }," . "\n";` in `while loop`. I used to pass it in `jQuery` like this: `initMarkers( [ $output ] );` but it doesn't work after `JSON` for some reason. Does it mess up `"\n"`? It used to be array or items _(count of while rounds)_ but now all items _counts_ as 1 item in that array.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using json_encode after storing your variables into a PHP object or array. When you write JSON for transmission via AJAX the syntax is much more terse. It's highly likely that trying to build a json string for something like that is going to give you issues. For instance, I'm pretty sure to write it like that you need to have it be { 'value1': 'value', 'value2': 'value' } (the property names need to be in quotes

Comment: @Solo I've updated the answer that should help explain what your JSON transmission should look like.

Comment: This approach works nicely. You think that there's any performance penalty or effect of any kind compared to previous approach? Especially if there's not 3 items but 5 000 - 10 000. Could you peek your code again and see what could I improve? For example, do I really need `array_push` in `while` loop or is it inexpensive?

Comment: You don't need array_push depending on what PHP version you are using. In my field, we have to work with all kinds of client environments that we can't control, so I have a tendency to use functions and syntax that aren't going to give me surprises when we reach deployment. The [] system for arrays wasn't introduced until PHP 5.4 I think. I can't remember. I just know it's never worth the hassle of having to go back and change it later vs just using syntax that is unlikely to deprecate anytime soon. Performance-wise I can't imagine how you'd improve it without changing the flow

Comment: If you've ever worked with some of the heavier CMS (like Drupal) and used DEVEL tools, when you see what PHP and MySQL are capable of doing in a single request, you'd probably sleep much better knowing. Now, if you are talking about thousands of lines of HTML being returned, well, bandwidth could be an issue. Server memory too depending on you build it. There is likely another way to accomplish your goal without returning thousands of lines of HTML, but that's for another question. :) glad this answer helped you and good luck!

Comment: oh, and one other thing you can do is view the network panel in Chrome (or other browser) developer tools. It will show you detailed information about your AJAX requests including response time and amount of data transmitted. This could be useful in narrowing potential performance issues if they come up.

Comment: Thank you for these additional comments. **PS!** Im only returning maximum of 30 sets of `html` at once _(Im using pagination)_ but the amount of data arrays for Google Maps can be as high as 10 000.. This could also cause some issues? I've thought about this for hours and I can't seem to think of a way to somehow cluster the data depending of map bounds or zoom level for example.

Comment: Yes, especially if you are using a marker for each. I haven't done it in a while, but Google has a layer system you can use to condense markers at lower zoom levels (zoomed out). One thing you have to keep in mind is that Google's one major rule for using its API is to not make Google look slow or have a poor user experience.  We're gonna get yelled at for keeping the comments going, but my suggestion is to build it first then gauge performance. There are always options depending on how much time/money you or your client has.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99510/discussion-between-solo-and-lawrence-johnson).